# Effective acceleration caused by graviy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

imagen you have something like this:

[image]

with $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\vec{g}$. I should now calculate the effective gravitational acceleration in the rest frame of the vehicle.

Can someone explain me exactly what that should be? I first though, it basically is the acceleration with which the vehice gets accelerated. So: $\vec{g}_{eff} = \sin(\theta)\vec g$ but it's actually $\vec{g}_{eff} = \cos(\theta)\vec g$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resolve $\vec g$ into two components, one parallel to the plane $g\sin\theta$ and one perpendicular to the plane $g\cos\theta$.
Note that in your question you had the wrong direction for these components as the direction is not that of $\vec g$.

When you are in the frame of the vehicle you and the vehicle are accelerating down the slope but there is no relative motion between you and the vehicle.
What you and the vehicle and the pendulum bob feel is the component of gravity which is perpendicular to the slope.
The line of the string connected to the pendulum bob will be at right angles to the slope and this is the "equilibrium" position of the pendulum in the frame of the vehicle.

If you make $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ the vehicle is accelerating downwards at $g\sin\frac\pi 2=g$.
The vehicle, you and the pendulum will be in free fall and feel weightless as $g\cos\frac \pi 2=0$.
So the pendulum can be in any orientation even horizontal.

**Update**

Imagine that you are in a lift which is accelerating downwards with an acceleration $a$ and you drop a mass $m$.
Relative t the ground the downward acceleration of the mass will be $g$ but relative to you in the lift the downward acceleration of the mass will be $g-a$.
So if you did an experiment in the lift to measure the acceleration of the mass you would find it to be $g-a$ and this is $g_{\rm eff}$

[image]

So to get $g_{\rm eff}$ as a vector quantity you have to do the vector subtraction $\vec g- \vec a$ as shown in the left hand diagram.
This is the same as you have done to find the relative velocity.
This example was relatively easy because all the vectors were collinear.

Now your slope example is a little more difficult in that the vectors are not collinear.
The acceleration of the "lift" is now $g \sin \theta$ down the slope.
To find $g_{\rm eff}$ you now need to subtract the acceleration down the slope from $g$ which is in the downward direction.
This is shown in the right hand diagram and from that you will see that $\vec g_{\rm eff}$ has a magnitude of $g \cos \theta$ and is directed down at right angles to the slope.

What this means is that in the "lift" which is accelerating down the slope  you would observe that the string of the pendulum is parallel to the direction of $\vec g_{\rm eff}$, if you measured the acceleration of free fall relative to the "lift" you would find its magnitude to be $g_{\rm eff}$ and the period of the pendulum $T$ would be $T=2 \pi \sqrt{\dfrac{l}{g \cos \theta}}$ where $l$ is the length of the pendulum.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get why $\vec{g}_\perp$ is $\vec g_{eff}$. Maybe you can tell me in words, what $\vec g_{eff}$ actually is.

Comment: @xotix I have updated my answer.